# Método update não atualiza no banco

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql

To com um problema na hora de editar, quando clico no botao ele busca as informações dos campos no console.log, ja tem o ID na rota tambem o problema é que nao atualiza as informações no banco, segue código:

```
exports.edit = function (req, res){
    var editaRegiao = req.body;
    var municipiosarray = [];

    for(var i = 0; i < editaRegiao.municipio.length; i++){
      municipiosarray.push(editaRegiao.municipio[i].id);
    }
    municipiosarray.toString()

    console.log(req.body);
      client.query('update cnes.regiao set descricao = ' + editaRegiao.descricao + ', municipio = ' + editaRegiao.municipio + 'where codigoregiao = ' + req.params.id, (err, result) => {
        if (err) return res.json(err);
        console.log(err);
        console.log(result);
        return res.json(result.rows);
      })
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Acredito que o problema esteja na montagem do SQL, pois o campo `descrição` me parece ser uma string, e da forma que está montado você não utiliza aspas (Válido também para os outros campos do tipo `string`.

Tente assim:

```
exports.edit = function (req, res){
    var editaRegiao = req.body;
    var municipiosarray = [];

    for(var i = 0; i < editaRegiao.municipio.length; i++){
      municipiosarray.push(editaRegiao.municipio[i].id);
    }
    municipiosarray.toString()

    console.log(req.body);
      client.query('update cnes.regiao set descricao = "' + editaRegiao.descricao + '", municipio = "' + editaRegiao.municipio + '" where codigoregiao = ' + req.params.id, (err, result) => {
        if (err) return res.json(err);
        console.log(err);
        console.log(result);
        return res.json(result.rows);
      })
};
```

E outra, faltava um espaço entre o seu município e a sua cláusula `where`.

Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: resolvido, era exatamente isso, obrigado!!

Comment: Não se esqueça de dar um + na resposta e de marcar como a melhor por gentileza.